# Unity creating animation for an an incision on a head model (brain surgery)

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, graphics, leap-motion, medical

Currently I'm trying to create something similar to the surgeon simulator game, but where the hands in the simulation will be controlled by leap motion. 
Im snuggling to create an animation where there is an incision made into the skull revealing the layers below. Any ideas on how I can achieve this, even if it needs creating on another software such as Maya then imported? 
I have currently downloaded a head model and placed a brain model within it but stuck on creating the incision animation to show the cut on the skull to reveal the brain.

I hope this makes sense. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Yeah, this is really broad, not to mention incredibly complicated as it involves the runtime modification of 3D meshes.

Comment: Most model systems you find these days won't work as Draco18s  points out. Because these models only model a surface. For surgery simulation you want models of a solid and these are not common.